# Changed or new files on a mapped network disk do not show in explorer even after refresh F5

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, shared-folders, mapped-drive

On a newly installed Windows 7 x64 machine I do not see changes made to files on a mapped network drive. I do not also see newly added files. I have tried searching registry for `dontrefresh` values as per [here](https://www.julianevansblog.com/2011/06/windows-7-file-and-folder-refresh-problem.html), but found nothing and it did not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me was a solution found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/947489ae-dc86-45f0-ad5e-463a62e1d59f/files-not-showing-up-in-networked-drive).

> 1. Open your Windows Explorer, and click organize.
> 2. Click Folder and search Option.
> 3. Under the General Tab, please check the box before “Automatically expand to current folder”.

[image]

As soon as I checked it, new and changed files showed in shared folder.

I have also set following registry key to 0:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters\DirectoryCacheLifetime`